# Disable classic view in IE, for a Lightning Only user

Tags: lightning-experience

We have setup a user as lightning only user by enabling permission "Hide Option to Switch to Salesforce Classic" in profile.

When the user logs into Salesforce using Chrome, it shows only lightning UI and there is no option to switch to classic. This works well.

When the user logs into Salesforce using IE11 (not IE Edge), it shows classic UI and there is no option to switch to lightning.

Our intent is to restrict classic view in all cases, even if they use IE11 or below and show an error message that only chrome should be going forward to access Salesforce.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce disabled IE 11 for performance and security reasons as of December 16th, 2017. If you want your IE 11 user to use the Lightning Experience, you need to enable [Extended Support for IE 11](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233325&language=en_US&type=1). Note that they mention IE 11 has potential security risks, and is at least 250% slower than using a modern browser, so your user won't have nearly as pleasant of an experience in IE 11. Note that this option will be removed in 2020 entirely, so your users will need to be upgraded to a modern browser before then.

---

To complete restrict access to Salesforce from IE 11, you can create a [Custom Login Flow in Visualforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow.htm&type=5). Basically, you can check to see if the user is in IE 11 or lower and refuse to let the user log in. The documentation explains how to do use the Custom Login Flow.

Comment: Extended use of IE11 with Lightning Experience is not enabled in the Org but it still goes to classic ui when logged in as a lightning user. We don't want to use lightning experience in IE11 but instead want to restrict user from using salesforce in IE11. Ideally i would hope Salesforce would show an error that salesforce is not enabled in IE11 so please use chrome since you are a lightning user.

Comment: @SFNinja Edited. You can create a Custom Login Flow to restrict users from using IE 11, and display an error to those users.

Comment: Thanks i went with the same approach earlier today and was able to restrict users.